# Обработка try catch

Tags: c++, visual-c++, исключения

Не могу поймать exception и соответственно, дебажить программу на C++...

```
try {
    int a = 1, b = 0;
    int c = a / b; // в данном случае имитирую exception для примера
  }
  catch (...) {
    int a = 1;
  }
```

Раньше я в catch ставил точку останова и мог отлавливать exception. Почему то сейчас не получается. Возможно, дело в настройках IDE? Использую Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Скорее всего "мусор" в обработчике, оптимизатор просто выбрасывает мусор, и в исключение не попадаете. int a=1; считается мусором, поскольку обьявленая переменная нигде не используется.

Comment: Вроде деление на 0 не является исключением C++

Comment: Если выбросил бы мусор, то получился бы пустой catch(...) {} - просто выходим из программы. А у меня подвисает в try {}

Comment: Делить на 0 нельзя, конечно же это исключение...

Comment: И ещё - в студии есть возможность перехватывать исключение в момент возникновения (см. Exception Settings), это бывает удобнее, чем ставить бряк в теле catch, т.к. сразу видно место где оно произошло.

Comment: При возникновении исключения - подвисает. Попробуйте поставить MessageBox(0,"error","error",0) или что-то в этом роде вместо  int a = 1;  Помогает DebugBreak() иногда.

Comment: nick_n_a, не доходит до catch, останавливается выше в try{}

Answer (score 4):

Исключения C++ и исключения процессора - совершенно разные вещи. Так вы ничего не поймаете.
Вам нужен [Structured Exception Handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680657%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - примерно так:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    __try {
        int a = 1;
        int c = a / (argc - 1); // в данном случае имитирую exception для примера
        cout << c << endl;
    }
    __except(GetExceptionCode() == EXCEPTION_INT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO)
    {
        cout << "Exception!\n";
    }
}
```

Ну, а если вам надо сгенерировать именно исключение C++ - то для этого есть `throw` - просто напишите что-то вроде `throw(0);`...

Comment: Никогда не пишите что-то вроде `throw(0)`.

Comment: @alexolut Возвращаю вам ваш комментарий: если человек намерен сразу же перехватить `catch(...)`, и то с целью отладки, и точно знает, что ничего другого делать не будет, то... :)

Answer (score 2):

[Ответ на ваш вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747934/c-catch-a-divide-by-zero-error/4748042#4748042) есть на английском SO. Вот небольшой перевод лучшего ответа:

---

Дело в том что по стандарту языка деление на ноль не считается исключительной ситуацией, но оно генерирует ошибку которая определяется на аппаратном уровне и возвращается обратно в операционную систему, которая затем оповещает вашу программу в определенной OS конкретным образом (например, завершая процесс).

Я полагаю, что в этом случае, происходит не исключение, а сигнал. Если это так то Операционная система прерывает основной поток управления вашей программы и вызывает обработчик сигнала, который - в свою очередь, - завершает работу программы.

Этот же тип ошибки появляется, когда вы разыменовываете нулевой указатель и ваша программа аварийно завершается по **SIGSEGV** сигналу, те происходит ошибка сегментации.

Вы можете использовать функции из заголовка `<csignal>`, чтобы сделать пользовательский обработчик для сигнала **SIGFPE** (который используется для исключения точки плавающего числа, но это можно использовать, для целочисленного деления на ноль - Но на самом деле я не очень уверен в этом). Однако следует отметить, что обработка сигналов является ОС-зависимой и MinGW каким-то образом "эмулирует" сигналы POSIX в среде Windows.

---

```
#include <csignal>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void handler(int a) {
    cout << "Signal " << a << " here!" << endl;
}

int main() {
    signal(SIGFPE, handler);
    int a = 1/0;
}
```

вывод

> Signal 8 here!

Comment: В Windows нет сигналов

Comment: только что код в windows запустил все работает

Comment: Это эмуляция нескольких сигналов из POSIX, но в Windows сигналов нет. Код может работать, но объяснение в ответе неверное — в windows нет сигналов.

Comment: Правильный ответ дан в ответе Harry — в Windows такие вещи правильно обрабатывать с помощью SEH; это канонический путь для Windows.

Comment: я думаю автор ответов слово сигнал употребляет в абстрактном смысле. раз библиотека эмуляции существует то почему бы не употребить это слово?

Comment: Потому что это неправильное употребление терминологии. Если уж очень хочется общей терминологии, то нужно употреблять _trap_ и уже из этого исходить. Сигналы это из мира UNIX, в Windows другая идеология.

Comment: а причом здесь идеология. у меня ide qtcreator а компилятор ms. консольные приложения я пишу с использованием ms технологий, а графические на qt + mingw. вместо нативного winforms. потому что все упрощается за счет этого. в кампании microsoft не вижу ни чего авторитетного, потому что они накладывают свои стандарты программирования и все запутывают. вот такая у меня идеология )

Comment: Я не понял Ваш последний комментарий. В Windows используется совершенно другая система взаимодействия приложения с ОС, в Windows не используются сигналы, но некоторые POSIX сигналы эмулируются, но это лишь эмуляция _некоторых_ сигналов. Говорить о сигналах, в контексте Windows, просто неверно.

Comment: объясню проще, я считаю что автор ответа слово **сигнал** употреблял относительно библиотеке `<csignal>`

Answer (score -3):

Нашел решение тут: stackoverflow.com/a/8226455/3909255

Нужно включить опцию `/EHa` в настройках проекта Visual Studio. Смотрим <kbd>Project Properties</kbd> → <kbd>C/C++</kbd> → <kbd>Code Generation</kbd>, измените Enable C++ Exceptions на значение "Yes With SEH Exceptions".

Comment: И как тут отличить деление а 0 от, например, присвоения по нулевому указателю?...

Comment: Мне главное обнаружить строку с ошибкой, а уже в ней понятно что не так...

Comment: Странно, что правильный ответ набрал отрицательные голоса )))

Comment: Не все пользователи RuSO свободно читают на английском. Если вы считаете, что ответ на EnSO отвечает на поставленный вопрос, сделайте перевод и укажите ссылку на источник.

Comment: Ответ правильный, но "стрёмный". Даже MSDN не рекомендует в общем случае им пользоваться...

Comment: Мне не нужно деление на 0, это я для примера указал... У меня в программе возникает эксепшион, я вижу в какой строчке и хочу пройти дебагом. try catch меня полностью устраивает. Не пойму почему ответ стрёмный? Не пойму что не так?

Comment: @sitev_ru не так то, что вместо того, чтобы привести суть ответа прямо в теле ответа вы ограничились ссылкой. Ответы-ссылки [не считаются качественными](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). Если бы вы не были автором вопроса - этот ответ давно бы уже удалили. Т.к. вы автор - то просто минусуют и ждут что вы все-таки превратите его в полноценный ответ.